# Odata Query can't be translated from Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, ef-core-3.1

I am trying to get the OData Query to work on .Net Core 3.1

Everything was working fine on .Net Core 2.1
now after the upgrade it says

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '$it' could not
>   be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be
>   translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a
>   call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
>   ToListAsync().

I have two tables

```cs
    public class WorkItem
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(128)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Resource> Resources { get; set; }

        public WorkItem(string name)
        {      
            Name = name;
        }
    }

public class Resource
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid WorkItemId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(128)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid StorageId { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        public ContentItem ContentItem { get; set; }

        public AppItem AppItem { get; set; }

        public Resource(Guid workItemId, string name, Guid storageId)
        {
            WorkItemId = workItemId;
            Name = name;
            StorageId = storageId;
        }
    }
```

and then the request uri looks as follow :

**_appItemsBaseUri/*response.Id*?$expand=Resources($filter=Name eq 'test2.pdf')";**

it successfully hit the api, filter the data and create the Odata SingleResult. If i expand it i can see that there is a WorkItem and the Resource is there.

```
var dto = dataset.Where(workItemId==responseId);
var res = SingleResult.Create(dto);
```

But it does not return from the API when i do

```
// This results in the error mentioned above.
return Ok(res);
```

the only way i can get it to work is to use it like this...

```cs
var dto = dataset.Where(workItemId==responseId);
var res = SingleResult.Create(dto).Queryable.FirstOrDefault();
return Ok(res)
```

I am using the following package versions 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Odata 7.3.0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.0

Please can you tell me how can i return the data without having to do a client evaluation (.Queryable.FirstOrDefault())?
and what is the reason that the code would need to do a client evaluation because there is no code that require the client evaluation that i can see?

Comment: Could you share more details about your api and Startup.cs?

Comment: Any update on the problem? Having similar problem

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue, not only on a single result, also when I try to filter a child collection. The problem seems to be Entity Framework 3.1.0. Looks like Entity Framework 3.1.0. would throw an exception if the query cannot be translated to sql query. Before, ef core was executing a query to get all data in memory and process the query after. 
The solution for me was to use either FirstOrDefault or ToList().AsQueryable(). But of course, this can lead to performance issues if we have lot of data in the table/s.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error as OP and arrived at a solution. I don't know if it solves OPs too because the DTO model wasn't posted.

For me, the child collection was a DTO List. I was missing the AutoMapper configuration mapping the DTO list property name to the Domain model property name.

```
CreateMap<CompetitionBarnAccount, CompetitionBarnAccountDTO>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Fees, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.BillingItems));
```