# Filter greater or equal results in LINQ expression error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

I am implementing the OData in my .netcore project and I am trying to apply some filters. When I use `odata/productshops?$filter=SellingPrice eq 20`, I get the product with the selling price 20.

But when I try to filter all product with selling price greater or equal 20:
`odata/productshops?$filter=SellingPrice ge 20`

I got an internal server error saying:

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<ProductShop>
    .Where(p => p.SellingPrice >= __TypedProperty_0)' could not be translated. 
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch 
to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

I though It has to do something with the type of field, which is decimal, so I tried write `20.0`, `20M` and `20.0M`, but still the same result and I can't tell why it is giving me this error.

How can I properly filter **greater or equal**?

My Startup config:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(app.ApplicationServices);
builder.EntitySet<ProductShopOData>("ProductShops");

app.UseMvc(routerBuilder =>
{
    routerBuilder.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(100).Count();
    routerBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
});
```

Controller:

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("Productshops")]
[Authorize]
public class ProductShopsController : ODataController
{
    private readonly MapperConfiguration _config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<ProductShop, ProductShopOData>();
    });

    private readonly Context _context;

    public ProductShopsController(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute]
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<ProductShopOData> GetProductShop()
    {
        return _context.ProductShops
            .ProjectTo<ProductShopOData>(_config);
    }
}
```

Used entity:

```
[Table("pro_product_shop_bind")]
public class ProductShop
{
    [Column("id")]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("status")]
    [Required]
    public RecordStatus Status { get; set; } = RecordStatus.Valid;
    
    [Column("shop_id")]
    [ForeignKey("Shop")]
    [Required]
    public int ShopId { get; set; }
    
    [Column("product_id")]
    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    [Required]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    
    [Column("type_code")]
    [Required]
    public ProductShopBindType TypeCode { get; set; }
    
    [Column("request_date")]
    public DateTime? RequestDate { get; set; }
    
    [Column("approval_date")]
    public DateTime? ApprovalDate { get; set; }
    
    [Column("request_status_code")]
    [Required]
    public RequestStatus RequestStatusCode { get; set; }

    [Column("is_hidden")]
    [Required]
    public bool IsHidden { get; set; } = true;

    [Column("is_automatic")]
    [Required]
    public bool IsAutomatic { get; set; } = true;
    
    [Column("delivery_status_id")]
    [ForeignKey("DeliveryStatus")]
    public int? DeliveryStatusId { get; set; }
    
    [Column("status_limit")]
    public short? StatusLimit { get; set; }
    
    [Column("below_limit_status_id")]
    [ForeignKey("BelowLimitStatus")]
    public int? BelowLimitStatusId { get; set; }
    
    [Column("above_limit_status_id")]
    [ForeignKey("AboveLimitStatus")]
    public int? AboveLimitStatusId { get; set; }
    
    [Column("zero_limit_status_id")]
    [ForeignKey("ZeroLimitStatus")]
    public int? ZeroLimitStatusId { get; set; }
    
    [Column("label_id")]
    [ForeignKey("Label")]
    public int? LabelId { get; set; }
    
    [Column("category_id")]
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    
    [Column("warranty_id")]
    [ForeignKey("Warranty")]
    public int? WarrantyId { get; set; }
    
    [Column("selling_price", TypeName = "decimal(10,2)")]
    [Required]
    public decimal SellingPrice { get; set; }
    
    [Column("other_price", TypeName = "decimal(10,2)")]
    [Required]
    public decimal OtherPrice { get; set; }

    [Column("use_default_price")]
    [Required]
    public bool UseDefaultPrice { get; set; } = true;

    [Column("price_changed")]
    [Required]
    public bool PriceChanged { get; set; } = false;
    
    [Column("shipper_id")]
    public int? ShipperId { get; set; }
    
    [Column("vat_type")]
    [Required]
    public VatType VatType { get; set; }

    [Column("must_be_stored")] 
    [Required] 
    public bool MustBeStored { get; set; } = true;

    public virtual Shop Shop { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual DeliveryTime DeliveryStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual DeliveryTime BelowLimitStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual DeliveryTime AboveLimitStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual DeliveryTime ZeroLimitStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual Label Label { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Warranty Warranty { get; set; }
}
```

EF Core version is 3.1.9.

**UPDATE:**

Found some kind of *"solution"* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59626078/odata-query-cant-be-translated-from-linq), but there is workaround with .ToList(), where got everything in the memory and convert it to AsQueryable(). But this is not optimal, how to make it properly?

Comment: What is your entity configuration like? Would be good to show that as well. Also what version of EF and odata are you using.

Comment: @Umair Sorry for long wait, got a lot stuff around. I post my entity, hope is that the configuration. And my EF version is 3.1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably bug with .NETcore version, in new .NET 5 is everything working nice.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by sending *wrong* query to database.
My guess is you are calculating **SellingPrice** outside of Query Method and that is causing the issue.

(I would post this as comment but I still dont have enough reputation - Sorry!)

Comment: I don't do anything more than is shown in the code.